# Oracle Linux: How can I source route from 2 interfaces with public addresses on the same host using nmcli?

Tags: linux, routing, oracle-linux, nmcli

I have an Oracle Linux 8 machine with two public addresses, similar to this example config (private addresses in example):

```
ens224: connected to ens224
        [...]
        ip4 default
        inet4 10.1.1.94/30
        route4 10.1.1.92/30 metric 104
        route4 default via 10.1.1.93 metric 104

ens256: connected to ens256
        [...]
        inet4 10.1.1.98/30
        route4 10.1.1.96/30 metric 102
```

The problem is that traffic going in to 10.1.1.98 (ens256) will have replies routed out through 10.1.1.93 (ens224) because it is the default gateway. This will not work in my case, as they are separate public addresses to different providers.

I need to ensure that requests to 10.1.1.94 are responded to via that interface but requests to 10.1.1.98 must be replied to via 10.1.1.97. This seems to require some sort of source-routing to ensure traffic selects the correct outgoing gateway.

I am trying to achieve this using 'nmcli' to conform to the latest best practice for interface management in OL. But so far I have not been able to get a configuration to work that does exactly what I need.

Comment: If I inderstand correctly you have two gateways to Internet (10.1.1.93 and 10.1.1.97)  and would like to use both, selecting the one matching the host's IP in use, like in this schematic? https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html (except it's not a router but an end node)

Comment: Anyway, doing this manually and getting to fit a manual setup inside the configuration of a tool are often two different things not very related.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. I will attempt the configuration you have pointed me to and live without nmcli. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

With the reference provided by A.B in the comments, this is the solution I came up with. It appears to solve the primary concern of the dual routes, but does not use nmcli to get the job done.

```
echo "10 public1" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
echo "20 public2" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

ip route add 10.0.0.92/30 dev ens224 src 10.0.0.94 table public1
ip route add default via 10.0.0.93 table public1
ip route add 10.0.0.96/30 dev ens256 src 10.0.0.98 table public2
ip route add default via 10.0.0.97 table public2
  
ip route add 10.0.0.92/30 dev ens224 src 10.0.0.94
ip route add 10.0.0.96/30 dev ens256 src 10.0.0.98

ip rule add from 10.0.0.94 table public1
ip rule add from 10.0.0.98 table public2
```

Please note that this does not persist across reboots, except for the rt_tables part. I resolved that by creating a custom service that runs the "ip" commands after network starts, but I think that is outside the scope of this question.

If anyone knows how to get the same result using nmcli, I would still appreciate it.